# Uploading a picture from ionic with angular to a php file

Tags: php, angular, ionic4

**The Problem:** Is that I cannot get the data of a file input on the client side, instead I get an empty array. Please see the results below. The field name for the file is `imageUrl`

**Ionic Angular Code:**

```
addPlace(
  title: string,
  description: string,
  imageUrl: string | File,
  price: number,
  dateFrom: Date,
  dateTo: Date,
  location: PlaceLocation
) {
  let generatedId: string;
  const newPlace = new Place(
    Math.random().toString(),
    title,
    description,
    imageUrl,
    price,
    dateFrom,
    dateTo,
    this.authService.userId,
    location
  );

  return this.http
    .post<{ id: string }>(environment.websiteApiPath + 'places/create.php', { ...newPlace })
    .pipe(
      switchMap(resData => {
        generatedId = resData.id;
        return this.places;
      }),
      take(1),
      tap(places => {
        newPlace.id = generatedId;
        this.inPlaces.next(places.concat(newPlace));
      })
    );
}
```

**PHP Code (create.php):**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

**Results:** It returns a list of array after using var_dump but the imageUrl is empty

```
<pre>array (
  'id' => '0.2705669762462872',
  'title' => '1',
  'description' => '2',
  'imageUrl' => 
  array (
  ),
  'price' => 3,
  'availableFrom' => '2019-10-13T12:28:38.242Z',
  'availableTo' => '2019-10-13T12:28:38.243Z',
  'userId' => 'abc',
  'location' => 
  array (
    'lat' => 14.5718818,
    'lng' => 121.05366169999998,
    'address' => '128 Pioneer St, Mandaluyong, Metro Manila, Philippines',
    'staticMapImageUrl' => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=14.5718818,121.05366169999998&zoom=8&size=500x300&maptype=roadmap
    &markers=color:red%7Clabel:Place%7C14.5718818,121.05366169999998
    &key=AIzaSyBdYunI5O8tvnzEgwTsXFKQFjy6qa6Oyso',
  ),
)</pre>
```

**Client Side Data:** I `console.log()` the data before sending an http request, below is the result.

```
{title: "1", description: "2", price: 3, dateFrom: "2019-10-13T20:28:38.242+08:00", dateTo: "2019-10-13T20:28:38.243+08:00", …}
dateFrom: "2019-10-13T20:28:38.242+08:00"
dateTo: "2019-10-13T20:28:38.243+08:00"
description: "2"
image: File {name: "check-up-the-sound-insulation-in-Germany.jpg", lastModified: 1569910148000, lastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 01 2019 14:09:08 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 6931, …}
location: {lat: 14.5718818, lng: 121.05366169999998, address: "128 Pioneer St, Mandaluyong, Metro Manila, Philippines", staticMapImageUrl: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?cen…↵    &key=AIzaSyBdYunI5O8tvnzEgwTsXFKQFjy6qa6Oyso"}
price: 3
title: "1"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue on my post has been fixed.

Instead of passing the data for requesting an HTTP request to the PHP server, I changed the JSON to formData.

**Ionic Angular Code:**

```
addPlace(
  title: string,
  description: string,
  imageUrl: string | File,
  price: number,
  dateFrom: Date,
  dateTo: Date,
  location: PlaceLocation
) {
  let generatedId: number;
  let generatedImage: string;
  let fetchedUserId: number;
  let newPlace: Place;
  return this.authService.userId.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(userId => {
      fetchedUserId = userId;
      return this.authService.token;
    }),
    take(1),
    switchMap(token => {
      if (!fetchedUserId) {
        throw new Error('No user id found!');
      }

      newPlace = new Place(
        null,
        title,
        description,
        null,
        price,
        dateFrom,
        dateTo,
        fetchedUserId,
        location
      );

      const uploadData = new FormData();
      uploadData.append('title', title);
      uploadData.append('description', description);
      uploadData.append('image', imageUrl);
      uploadData.append('price', price.toString());
      uploadData.append('title', title);
      uploadData.append('date_from', this.dateConvert(dateFrom));
      uploadData.append('date_to', this.dateConvert(dateTo));
      uploadData.append('user_id', fetchedUserId.toString());
      uploadData.append('address', location.address );
      uploadData.append('lat', location.lat.toString());
      uploadData.append('lng', location.lng.toString());
      uploadData.append('staticMapImageUrl', location.staticMapImageUrl );
      return this.http
        .post<{ id: number, image: string }>(`${environment.websiteApiPath}places/create.php?auth=${token}`, uploadData );
    }),
    switchMap(resData => {
      generatedId = resData.id;
      generatedImage = resData.image;
      return this.places;
    }),
    take(1),
    tap(places => {
      newPlace.id = generatedId;
      newPlace.imageUrl = generatedImage;
      this.inPlaces.next(places.concat(newPlace));
    })
  );
}
```

I removed the following code below for the PHP File:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Instead I used `$_POST` and `$_FILES`